# how to double scroll in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i've two tables. Both of them a scrollable. How can i douplicate scroll, like if table 1 is scrolling, table 2 might be scrollin as well or reverse. 
Here in image below you can see concept. Unfortunately i haven't any code yet.

[image]

Comment: bind the scroll events of both together

Comment: On `scroll` event, set `scrollTop` of the other one to the `scrollTop` of the current one.

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @Giuppox, it's not necesary jQuery -really in Angular it's innecesary use jQuery-

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two divs like

```
<div class="area dos">
  <div class="move" [style.top]="top">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="area uno" #one (scroll)="scroll(one)">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```

the function scroll is like

```
scroll(one:any)
  {
    this.top=-one.scrollTop+'px'
  }
```

The "key" is that the "area dos" has position relative, and "move" position absolute, so we can change [style.top] of the "move" div

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uctrfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Gracias, i've made it with scrollTop, but i've got one issue. It must scroll in reverse too.